# In React js how do we set Props in child component and pass the props value to grand parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a value to Props onClickCapture in child component and pass it to grand parent 
component.

These are the three components:

First component:

```
class StdntRuleLookup extends React.Component{
handleSelectStdntFromSearch = (stdValue) => { 
        this.setState({stdntCd:stdValue});
 }

render(){
return (                 
     <StdntLinkField onClose={!this.showModal} show={this.state.show} onClickCapture= 
     {this.handleSelectStdntFromSearch }/>
 )
 }
 };
```

When show modal is clicked the modal opens up and calls second component StdntLinkField and it displays the results in the griddle and onClickCapture props is passed to griddle:

Second Component:

```
 var columnMeta = [ 
                      {
                          "columnName": "select",
                          "order": 2,
                          "displayName":" ",
                          "locked": false,
                          "visible": true,
                          "customComponent": SelectLinkField,
                          "customComponentMetadata": {
                        "onClickCapture":this.props.onClickCapture
                        }
                      }
                      ];
  var stdntJSONResults = this.state.stdntLookupList.map(function (user,i) { 
  return (          {                     
                            "stdntCd": user.stdntCd,
                            "index" : i
                    }               
                  );
                 }.bind(this));
 };
 return( 
 <Griddle results={stdntJSONResults }
             columns={["stdntCd","select"]}

             showFilter={true}
             showPager={true} 
             showSettings={true}
             columnMetadata={columnMeta}
             resultsPerPage = {50}
             useFixedLayout = {false}
             useFixedHeader={false}
             sortAscendingComponent={<span className="fa fa-sort-up"></span>}
             sortDescendingComponent={<span className="fa fa-sort-down"></span>}
             columnFilterFunc={myColumnFilterFunc}
             tableClassName="table"/>
  )}
  };
```

Third component is custom component SelectLinkField when "select" is clicked from griddle results in 
  modal:

```
      class SelectLinkField extends React.Component{  
       constructor() {
       super();

      this.onClickCapture = this.onClickCapture.bind(this);
        };

      onClickCapture(stdntCd){          
         var stdntCd= null;         
         stdntCd= this.props.rowData.stdntCd;
          this.props.onClickCapture(stdntcd); 
          };

     render(){
     return (
         <a onClick={this.props.metadata.customComponentMetadata.onClickCapture}> 
            Select
         </a>         
          )
        }};
```

How can I set the value of this.props.rowData.stdntCd to onClickCapture props in "SelectLinkField" component so that this.props.rowData.stdntCd value is available in "StdntRuleLookup" component from onClickCapture props?

Comment: You either keep passing down callbacks (just like if it was a parent-child relationship, but one more), use a `Context`, or switch to a more flexible state management system.

Comment: ok will try creating one more parent child relationship component and pass this.props.rowData.stdntCd to onClickCapture props in that component and see if that works. Thank You